# Saludo personalizado en función de la hora

Tags: javascript, date, function, text, time

he desarrollado una función que permite saludar al usuario de una manera u otra en función de la hora, pero me he dado cuenta que el intervalo de tiempo nocturno no funciona y querría saber por qué.

```js
 function mostrarSaludo(){
 var texto = "";
 var ahora=new Date(); 
 var hora=ahora.getHours();
  if(hora>=6 && hora<13){
   texto="Buenos días";  
  }
  if(hora>=13 && hora<21){ 
   texto="Buenas tardes";
  }
  if (hora>=21 && hora<6){ 
   texto="Buenas noches";
  }
    document.getElementById('saludo').innerHTML = texto;
    document.getElementById('saludo2').innerHTML = texto;
       }
```

```html
<button onclick="mostrarSaludo()"> Saludar</button>
<div id="saludo"></div>
<div id="saludo2"></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Una mejora en el código sería hacer una estructura `if_else`, ya que si entra en la una condición no necesita comprobar las restantes, y en este caso el horario nocturno queda comprendido en el `else`.

```js
function mostrarSaludo(){
    var texto = "";
    var ahora=new Date(); 
    var hora=ahora.getHours();
    hora = 22;
    if (hora>=6 && hora<13) {
        texto="Buenos días";  
    } else if (hora>=13 && hora<21) { 
        texto="Buenas tardes";
    } else { 
        texto="Buenas noches";
    }
   document.getElementById('saludo').innerHTML = texto;
   
} 
mostrarSaludo();
```

```html
<div id="saludo"></div>
```

Comment: las demás respuestas son eficaces, pero esta es la mas eficiente.

Comment: Muchas gracias Carmen, probaré a ver que pasa, pero tiene buena pinta.

Answer (score 1):

No existe ningun numero que sea mayor o igual que 21 y menor que 6. 
En cambio tienes que comprobar que sea mayor que 21 y menor que 24 que serian las 00 y a parte comparar si es menor que 6.

```js
var texto = "";
var hora=23
    if(hora>=6 && hora<13){
        texto="Buenos días";  
    }
    if(hora>=13 && hora<21){ 
        texto="Buenas tardes";
    }
    if (hora>=21 && hora <=24 || hora<6){ 
        texto="Buenas noches";
    }
console.log(texto);
```

Answer (score 1):

Tu problema esta en que la validación le pones `&&` para el saludo de "Buenas noches"

> En el caso de la noche no existe un numero **mayor o igual a 21 y menor
>   a 6**

---

Usando un `||` puedes indicar un rango *mayor o igual a 21* **o** *menor a 6*, lo que te da como resultado el rango de horas de la noche, dado que `.getHours()` de `Date` devuelve entre 0 y 23 no tendrías problemas.

Ejemplo:

```js
var texto = "";
var ahora=new Date('December 25, 1995 23:15:30'); // Crea la fecha que se indica entre ''
var hora= ahora.getHours();

    if(hora >= 6 && hora<13){
        texto="Buenos días";  
    }
    if(hora>=13 && hora<21){ 
        texto="Buenas tardes";
    }
    if (hora>=21 || hora<6){ 
        texto="Buenas noches";
    }
    
   console.log(texto);
```

Answer (score 1):

La ultima condicion esta mal.  Una hora no puede ser simultaneamente menor que 21 y mayor que 6.  En lugar de usar AND tienes que usar OR.  Te dejo un ejemplo para que veas que funciona:

```js
function mostrarSaludo(){
    var texto = "";
    var ahora=new Date(); 
    var hora=ahora.getHours();
    hora = 22;
    if(hora>=6 && hora<13){
        texto="Buenos días";  
    }
    if(hora>=13 && hora<21){ 
        texto="Buenas tardes";
    }
    if (hora>=21 || hora<6){ 
        texto="Buenas noches";
    }
   document.getElementById('saludo').innerHTML = texto;
   
} 
mostrarSaludo();
```

```html
<div id="saludo"></div>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias alanfcm, probaré a ver que tal.